# bash + regular expression + capture java version

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, regular-expression

how to capture the `jdk1.8.0_112` under `/usr/jdk64`

```
 /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/
```

while jdk1.8.0_112 is example

and could be any other version as

```
jdk1.7.0_112
jdk3.8.2_112
jdk1.8.0_117
jdk1.2.0_112
jdk2.7.66_112
jdk1.8.2_111
jdk1.23.0_117
jdk9.2.093_112
```

Comment: Unclear: What do you mean by "capture"? Is the list that you show names of subdirectories that exists under `/usr/jdk64`? What is wrong with expanding the shell glob `/usr/jdk64/jdk*`? What are you expecting as the result (a string in a variable?)

Comment: What’s the higher-level problem you’re trying to solve? Why do you need this particular string, and what are you planning on doing with it?

Comment: How is this related to `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
find /usr/jdk64/* -prune -type d -name 'jdk*' | grep -P 'jdk\d+\.\d+\.\d+_\d+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for the regexp you need is:

```
grep -E "jdk([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9_]+)"
```